# 60s pulp book: spies with neck implants melt when captured and turn out to be alien scouts

Tags: story-identification, pulp

Written and set around the late 60s/early 70s. Members of "The Agency" (FBI/CIA type organisation) are investigating the origins of spies who have capsules or something implanted in the back of their neck, and who melt when captured. Eventually they discover they are aliens, scouts for an invasion fleet. The humans also meet good aliens who help earth build their own fleet, which meets the enemy in the outer solar system in the final chapters.

Comment: When did you read this book? Was it new?

Comment: Approx 1974, have edited original post, also thanks for adding story identification tag, couldn't find appropriate tag earlier.

Comment: Excellent. Now can you add *any* more details? Name of people, places? More plot points.

Comment: About an adult book I half-read when I was eight forty years ago? No! Well I could, but I wouldn't know if they were from other books, tropes or dreams :-)

Comment: That's totally ok, *any* details are good.

Comment: This sounds as if it might be a novelization from a TV series.  Were the aliens perchance missing a single finger, all of them the *same* finger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This outline has some similarities to *The Puppet Masters* by R.A. Heinlein. It came out in 1951 but was reprinted by Signet/NAL in 1971 and 1975.

Comment: Can you also add which details seem similar?

Comment: Certainly has some similarities, will check it out thanks.

Comment: Yes, allowing for several decades of memory blurring, i think this is it, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This seems very similar to *The Invaders*, a TV series that ran in 1967 and 1968.  Aliens had invaded Earth, and been discovered by one man who spent the series trying to get others to help him fight them.  The aliens (almost all) had a deformed pinky finger, and in a couple episodes were seen in their alien form or reverting to that form -- an effect that might have been describe in the novelization as "melting".

What you read was probably the novelization, likely a collection of several episodes in a single cover, similar to the novelizations of other popular SF series such as *Star Trek* or *Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea*.

Comment: Yeah I think its the Puppet Masters (see below) but its always good to meet someone who has watched "The Invaders". Its an interesting show, its also interesting how different the pacing of the show is compared to modern series.